# django-export data real value instead of the foreign_id

Tags: django

plz can you say me how to export data foreign_id instead of the real value as an excel file in django

Students.py

```
class Students(models.Model):
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('m', 'male'),
        ('f', 'female'),
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True,)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=MY_CHOICES)
    school= models.ForeignKey(school, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True,blank=True,) 
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Student'
```

admin.py

```
from school.models import School,fields
class StudentsResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Students
        school= fields.Field(id='school',attribute='school',widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(School, 'school'))
```

school.py

```
class School(models.Model):
   school= models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True,)
'''
Thank you for your help

[excel file]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLGZM.png
```

Comment: You want to export only the ID value of the school?

Comment: What´s your question? Give us more information and what are you struggeling with.

Comment: Hi @medou Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want your question can be answered, please be cleared about what you want to achieve.

Comment: i want to export name of the school instead of id to an .xlsx file

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLGZM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django's double underscore notation to access related fields.

So this example would work for the name of the school on the related model, assuming a school instance has a name;

```py
class StudentResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('school__name',)
```